# How to parse a mulidimensional JSONString in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a JSON-formatted `String` that has a singular key-value pair and a `Map` consisting of various `String`-typed keys and values within it, as follows:

```
"{"Key":"value","Map":{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2",...}}"
```

What I *want* to do is convert this `String` into a `JSONObject` (because I have other code that can easily interpret a `JSONObject`). My first instinct was to use a parser (`JSONParser`) like the code snippet below...

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object o = new JSONParser();

o = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonStr);
JSONObject j = (JSONObject) o;
```

…but I got a `ParseException` instead of the convenient `JSONObject`. Why is that? Should I be treating the `String` differently, since it has a `Map` inside of it? Or am I doing something beyond the capabilities of a `JSONParser`?

Comment: Likely your input is actually not valid json. I'd recommend to print the string before parsing, as the source literal / construction code might make errors hard to spot (e.g. quotes need to be escaped inside a Java string literal -- it's easy to add errors there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... but I got a `ParseException` instead of the convenient `JSONObject`. Why is that?

If you got a `ParseException`, that means that what you think is JSON is (in fact) not valid JSON.  It is not a problem with your parsing code or the `JSONObject` parser.  It is either a problem with the way the (supposed) JSON was produced in the first place, or with "channel" by which it reached the code that was supposed to parse it.

---

> Should I be treating the string differently, since it has a map inside of it?

Nope.

I note that your example code snippets are not sufficiently clear / complete to be able to tell exactly what you are doing.  (In future, please provide a real [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than code snippets that don't make a lot of sense<sup>1</sup> ... and certainly can't be compiled and run.)  But there is nothing to indicate that *that* code is the cause of the `ParseException`.

> Or am I doing something beyond the capabilities of a `JSONParser`?

Nope.  A JSON parser can cope with any JSON *provided that it is well-formed*.

---

To fix this, you are going to need to work out why the parser thinks your JSON is bad, and work back to the root cause of the badness.

---

<sup>1 - For example, why are you assigning a `JSONParser` object to a variable of type `Object`?</sup>